# How best we can allocate?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

Thank you for this opportunity to share my post here

Advanced thanks to the people who answered my post

Problem: There are $5$ items and cost of these items in dollars are $3$,  $3.2$,  $4.5$,  $2.5$,  $1.7$ respectively. How  can we allocate $100$ dollars to buy the above items in a such way in order to get **maximum number of items** in our hand.

1. All types of items should be covered
2. Repetition of items may be allowed
3. Maximum number of items should be purchased
4. Not necessary to spend entire $100$. but, maximum amount should spend near to $100$ or with entire $100$
5. We need to buy each kind of item as much as possible

How to solve this type of problem?
Kindly answer
Thanks again

Comment: Intuitively, buying the cheapest item as much as possible will give us the most items for our money

Comment: ALL items should be covered. Can you write math formula for it

Comment: Then you buy a single of each item, and spend the rest of the cash on the cheapest, for a total of $100 - (3 + 3.2 + 4.5 + 2.5) = 86.8$, $86.8/1.7 \approx 51$, so 55 items in total.

Comment: Need to buy each item as much as more we can buy. In such case, how we can allocate?

Comment: So you should buy an almost equal amount of all items?

Comment: Not necessary to buy equal. One is may be more, and other is may be less. All should cover and try to buy more of each kind.

Comment: In what distribution, we can get optimal number of each type. As well as in maximum in total

Comment: In that case, you can divide your 100 dollars by the sum of the prices of the objects. Then with the cash left over, buy the chepeast items. In your case, this results in: $100 = 6 * (3 + 3.2 + 4.5 + 2.5 + 1.7) + 10.6 = 6 * (3 + 3.2 + 4.5 + 2.5 + 1.7) + 1.7 + 2.5 + 3 + 3.2 + 0.2$, so we can buy 6 sets of items, and 4 extra items with the cash left over, for a total of 34 items.

Comment: Its looks great. can we put the same in the formula notation. instead of more calculations?

Comment: I think the above one is also solution. But not may be optimal. We may get more in total. I am not sure. can we have any formula for it. If this is the only way of computation. Then its OK. I have learnt something from you and this site. Thanks for both.

Comment: It is definitely possible to get more items for the same amount of dollars, but the question is, what restrictions are put in place? Is it that all items must be bought almost equally, then my previous answer of 34 is correct. Is it that all items must be bought at least once, then my first answer of 55 would be correct. If there are no restrictions at all, then the answer would be $100/1.7 \approx 57$. A general formula depends on which restrictions there are in this case. I assume we are in the 34 case, so I'm writing a general formula for you now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be the amount of dollars to spend, let $a_1, a_2, ..., a_k$ be the objects we want to buy, with prices $p_1, p_2, ..., p_k \in \mathbb{N}$. As we can reorder these items freely, we can assume that their prices are ordered increasingly, that is: $p_1 \leq p_2 \leq ... \leq p_k$.

Define $p = \sum_{i=0}^k p_k$, the total price of all items.

We can write $n = qp + r$, for some $q,r \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0 \leq r < p$. This is equivalent to dividing $n$ by $p$ with rest. As we want to buy all items an almost equal amount, we therefore by $q$ sets of all items, and then have $r$ dollars left over.

With these $r$ dollars, we can buy the items $p_1, p_2, ..., p_k$, until we run out of dollars. We always buy the least expensive item first, so we have as much cash left over as possible. In this case, the question becomes (and I don't think there is a simple formula for this):

What is the largest value of $j\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $r > \sum_{i=0}^j p_i$.

This value of $j$ is the amount of items we can buy with the remaining $r$ dollars.

Putting al this together: We can buy $q$ sets of $k$ items, and with the remaining $r$ dollars we can buy $j$ items, so in in total we can buy $qk+j$ items with our $n$ dollars.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For item $i$, let $c_i$ be the cost, and let integer decision variable $x_i$ be the number bought.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_i x_i$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_i c_i x_i &\le 100 \\ 
x_i &\ge 1 &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}
An optimal solution is $x=(1,1,1,1,51)$, with optimal objective value $55$.

If you want the numbers of items bought to vary by no more than $1$, you can impose additional constraint
$$-1 \le x_i - x_j \le 1 \quad \text{for all $i<j$}.$$
An optimal solution is $x=(7,7,6,7,7)$, with optimal objective value $34$.